# Cómo solucionar DateTime::__construct(): error en PHP 7?

Tags: php

El error no influye en el rendimiento de la página web, pero tengo miles de registros en mi php-errors.log con este mensaje:

> [12-May-2017 15:19:17 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards: 
>   DateTime::__construct(): We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for
>   'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /homepages/.../crm.php
>   on line 401

En linea 401 de crm.php tengo esto:

```
$current_date=date("d-m-Y");

$date11 = new DateTime($current_date);
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo evitarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se va si agregas la zona horaria al construct:

```
$current_date=date("d-m-Y");
$fecha = new DateTime($current_date, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```